# create info popup in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I create an info popup in Flutter similar to the attached image?

[image]

Comment: You've been on StackOverflow long enough to know that this is not how you ask questions here. You show no code, and you are asking people to write you code from scratch. Please follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

You can play with the values. I am just giving you an idea how you can achieve that.

**Full code:**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  void _showOverlay(context) async {
    final box = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final offset = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    final entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (_) => Positioned(
        top: offset.dy - 40,
        left: offset.dx - 120,
        child: _buildInfo(),
      ),
    );

    Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    entry.remove();
  }

  Widget _buildInfo() {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red[200],
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Text('This is an info button'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('What is this'),
            IconButton(
              key: _key,
              icon: Icon(Icons.info),
              onPressed: () => _showOverlay(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this library you may find your solution
popover : https://pub.dev/packages/popover,
popup_menu : https://pub.dev/packages/popup_menu/example